# How to initialize template variable by constructor and print out it?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm reading chapter 19 of
 [programming principles and practice using C++]

but I don't know how to initialize template variable using constructor and print it by function.
Can anyone tell me the simplest way to do it?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "C:/std_lib_facilities.h"

template<typename T>
struct S {
    T val;
    S(T theval) { val = theval; }
};

template<typename T> 
void print(T theval) // function template
{
    cout <<theval<< '\n';
}

int main()
{
    S<int> x1 {1};


    print(1); //OK
    print(x1);//error:C2697
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x1` is a struct of type `S<int>` but `cout` doesn't know how to deal with those.

Answer (score 2):

You should also specify `print` for your structure e.g. just add :

```
template<typename T> 
void print(S<T> s)
{
    cout << s.val << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were passing struct S element to your print() function, but it expects an argument to be type of theval. The right solution is to just either pass `.val` element of your new x1 object:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct S {
    T val;
    S(T theval) { val = theval; }
};

template<typename T> 
void print(T theval) // function template
{
    std::cout << theval << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    S<int> x1(1);

    print(1); //OK
    print(x1.val);
return 0;
}
```

...or to change the definition of print() function:
 make it expect struct S element `S<T> s` and then `std::cout << s.val << "\n";` inside of it:

```
template<typename T> 
void print(S<T> s) // function template
{
    std::cout << s.val << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `1) Write S<int> x1(1) rather than { } braces.`  Why ?

Comment: Of course, since both ways are correct, it is rather not so important. Edited my answer, sir.

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to it rather than answering directly I would strongly suggest you to go through this tutorial and try to get answer by yourself as it is searchable problem.

Kindly follow this link(Your question's answer is available right there in this tutorial):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part

Answer (score 0):

Your S class does not have operator<< for printing to cout, add one:

```
template<typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const S<T>& dt)
{
    os << dt.val;
    return os;
}
```

and if you ever would like to make `val` a private part o your struct/class (which is recomended) then make `operator<<` a friend:

```
template<typename T>
struct S {
private:    
    T val;
    public:
    S(T theval) { val = theval; }

    template<typename X>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const S<X>& dt);
};

template<typename X>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const S<X>& dt)
{
    os << dt.val;
    return os;
}
```